# Expect 204 found 400 in REST API

Tags: rest-assured

Please suggest possible solution for the below Rest API code.
I just tried to assign the created issue to one person in JIRA.
There is another piece of code where I have created one issue. That works without any issue but this is not working.
Here is the code below:
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class JIRA_Update {
Properties prop=new Properties();
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void getData() throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\files\\environment.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
    }
    
@Test
    public void assignJIRA()
    {
        RestAssured.baseURI=prop.getProperty("HOST2");
        given().header("content-type","application/json").
        header("Cookie","JSESSIONID="+reusableMethods.getSessionID()).
        body("{" + 
                "\"name\":\"Ansuman\"" + 
                "}").
        when().
        put("/rest/api/2/issue/10004/assignee").
        then().statusCode(204);
    }
```

Below error I got:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.7.0
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\AnsumanPrasad\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1620457977\testng-customsuite.xml

Request method: PUT
Request URI:    http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10100/assignee
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Cookie=JSESSIONID=D7A94750CC1AC453FB60054EFCC0340B
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "name": "Ansuman"
}
Request method: PUT
Request URI:    http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10100/assignee
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Cookie=JSESSIONID=D7A94750CC1AC453FB60054EFCC0340B
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "name": "Ansuman"
}
HTTP/1.1 400 
X-AREQUESTID: 1130x39x1
X-ASESSIONID: 8tbrup
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-ASEN: SEN-L15668709
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=B1FY-RQO1-RBZ3-U5XU_bcbf0b7117c072a927e06729133c3b7fa914b65b_lin; Path=/
X-AUSERNAME: admin
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2020 13:21:12 GMT
Connection: close

{
    "errorMessages": [
        
    ],
    "errors": {
        "assignee": "User 'Ansuman' does not exist."
    }
}
FAILED: assignJIRA
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <204> but was <400>.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:493)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:674)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:126)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:134)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.super$2$statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy:142)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
    at Demo.JIRA_Update.assignJIRA(JIRA_Update.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:715)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:907)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1237)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:51)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:85)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@52af6cff: 96 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@9f70c54: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@50f8360d: 11 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6615435c: 87 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@617c74e5: 156 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [TestListenerAdapter] Passed:0 Failed:0 Skipped:0]: 23 ms
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-changelog-get), `accountId` need to be passed in request body, basic authentication need to be passed as `.basic("username", "password")`. But you haven't done those things.

Comment: Also add a `.log().all()` and paste the response here so we'll have a clearer picture

Comment: @WilfredClement.. I have edited the error log after applying .log().all()
kindly check once.

Comment: @AnsumanPrasadPati Please use `.log().all()` after `given()` and after `then()` so you capture the request and the response traffic, you have posted only the request traffic here

Comment: @WilfredClement I have edited again. please check now.

Comment: Great, Look at the response log the response explains everything`assignee": "User 'Ansuman' does not exist.`

Comment: @WilfredClement I understood the log. But the thing is, I can manually able to assign the name in JIRA as I am assigning my name only, but using code I am getting this error. How to solve it? Why I am getting this error that also making me confuse.

If you don't mind please guide me.

Comment: Did u try it from postman ? Give it a try from postman and let me know if it works and if it does paste the console output of postman as well and we'll figure it out

Comment: @WilfredClement I have tried it in postman too. Found the same piece of error, saying "user doesn't exist".

Comment: Did you figure this out, @AnsumanPrasadPati?

Comment: No. didn't find the solution yet. If you know please help me out. @reowil

Comment: @AnsumanPrasadPati I don't have the solution, unfortunately. But did you check (and double check) that the assignee "Ansuman" actually exists? What the Jira GUI displays and what it internally calls the user is probably two different things? When I start typing a user name in the Jira GUI "asignee" field, Jira autocompletes for me with the "user friendly version", but I'm pretty sure that what Jira calls the user internally is not the same as the display name. Example: My display name could be "Elaine Marley", while the actual username in Jira internally could be "elaine.marley@company.no"

Comment: As you said, I agree with your words. It might possible. So I have tried in both way by simply giving the username as well as by providing mail id too. It rejects both. While the same thing is working without any issue in JIRA GUI. @reowil